# Mariadb keeps crashing after sometime

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb-10.3

I am getting a weird problem with Mariadb server. After starting the service after few mins the service will go down automatically. Upon checking status this is what I find.

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Thu 2023-03-23 12:32:26 UTC; 19h ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 2260927 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2262690 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2262649 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2262727
   Status: "Waiting for page cleaner"
    Tasks: 10 (limit: 11310)
   Memory: 136.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           ├─2211841 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr
           ├─2218737 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr
           ├─2220075 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr
           ├─2222515 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr
           └─2262727 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr

Mar 23 12:17:25 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]:
 mariadb.service: Found left-over process 2220075 (mysqld) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.

Mar 23 12:17:25 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]:
 This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.

Mar 23 12:17:25 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]:
 mariadb.service: Found left-over process 2222515 (mysqld) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.

Mar 23 12:17:25 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]:
 This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.

Mar 23 12:17:25 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal mysqld[2262727]:
 2023-03-23 12:17:25 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.28-MariaDB) starting as process 2262727 ...

Mar 23 12:22:25 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]:
 mariadb.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.

Mar 23 12:27:25 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]:
 mariadb.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Skipping SIGKILL.

Mar 23 12:32:26 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]:
 mariadb.service: State 'stop-final-sigterm' timed out. Skipping SIGKILL. Entering failed mode.

Mar 23 12:32:26 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]:
 mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.

Mar 23 12:32:26 ip-172-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]:
 Failed to start MariaDB 10.3 database server.
```

Anybody got an Idea to fix this issue?

Comment: There simply shouldn't be more than one mysqld process running in the cgroup. Recommend attempting the upstream [service file](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.3/support-files/mariadb.service.in) after replacing the `@sbin@` like build variables.